# iOS: How to take a screenshot of App Store programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot, mobile-application

I want to take a screenshot of App Store Search Page programmatically. I know there are lots of answers for taking screenshots of Your Own App, but what I want is to take the screenshot of App Store. Is there a way to do this?

I am completely new to iOS development. So if you can point out how to tweak the codes in other questions' solution to suit my need, it will also be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that kind of stuff outside your own app.

Comment: Since iPhone users can take screenshots of their phone freely by pressing 2 buttons, why automating this is not allowed? Or is there a way to programmatically control my own iPhone?

Comment: In a word, *security*. Apple places a large - I'd even say top - priority on (1) apps working inside a sandbox and (2) putting decisions like taking screenshots into the user's hands. What reason *should* they give you - a developer to automatically take a screenshot without the user's consent?

Comment: No, I don't want to take screenshots of others' phones. Mine would be sufficient. I just don't want to do this manually. I want the program to run this as I schedule. @dfd

Comment: @Athena you can't - that'd be an easily exploitable feature so Apple won't allow it. You'd have better luck describing the reason you need to do this, as there may be an alternative.

Comment: @Voldemort Thanks for your response! I will think it over to see if there's other way to achieve what I want instead of taking screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this.

iOS has a strong emphasis on security and privacy. Allowing any app to take screenshots of other apps would be a privacy and security issue.

Comment: What if I don't use an app to take the screenshot? Can I just connect iphone with my pc to do it? I don't really see the difference between taking a screenshot manually by pressing buttons on my phone and taking screenshot programmatically?

Comment: The difference is both major *and* critical! Would you want to find out that an app that (1) you didn't write and (2) you have on your phone was taking screenshots on it's own? Of course not! Now, if you wish to code your own app to (1) take screenshots of (2) views and images **within** the app you wrote "programmatically"... of course you can. But please, understand that it's not what you say you want to do.

Comment: @dfd First of all, I am not saying that I want to write an app to take a screenshot of anyone's phones silently, which is obviously a threat to iphone users. I just want a way to take screen shot of **my own** phone. Let's say I want a screenshot of Search page of App Store, which can easily be done by pressing Home and Sleep buttons. (The screenshot is just a UI of App Store, which is accessible to the public). I simply want to automate this. I am not saying that I am going to use everyone's phone and take screenshots of their phones either manually or programmatically.

Comment: I guess the *critical* question - not for me, but for Apple - is **why**? I frequently take screenshots - eve short videos or what is called an "app preview". (It's part of trying to be an individual iOS developer.) So far, the *only* way I know - for both an app preview and until I found a better way - for screenshots and/or a short video - **is** manually. So far.... you've shown no code. You've shown nothing you've tried. Worst? You've shown no **reason** for why you simply cannot take the *manual* route. Why automate something you simply *do not* normally automate?

Comment: The fact that I didn't share codes doesn't mean that I hadn't tried them. I tried the codes for taking screenshots of one's own app and realized that it didn't serve my purpose afterwards. So I don't think it's relevant to put the codes here. And I know this is a rather unusual question, but isn't here the right place to get brilliant answers for difficult questions? Also I don't want to take screenshot manually not because I am lazy, but because of other use case. So I think instead of attacking the legitimacy of the question, it's better to peacefully discuss it, don't you think? (wink)